# Is it possible to insert a new attribute and update old attribute in same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here i am updating xml where inserting a new attribute value2 at the same time replacing Value1="NN" to Value1=''. But only replace query is executing at all time.

Is it possible to update both queries at same time? If so how can i use it.

```
set @sql = N'
            set @mxgraphxml.modify(''replace value of Value1 {''} into (/mxGraphModel[1]/root/Cell[1][' + CAST(@rowID as nvarchar(100)) + '])'')
            set @mxgraphxml.modify(''insert (attribute Value2 {data(/mxGraphModel/root/Cell[' + CAST(@rowID as nvarchar(100)) + ']/@Value)}) as last into (/mxGraphModel[1]/root[1]/Cell[' + CAST(@rowID as nvarchar(100)) + '])'')'
            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: You can't do it in the same query but you could do it in the same transaction -- this would make it atomic in terms of locking.

Comment: @Hogan is there any way we can make it work both updates?

Comment: you are not showing 1 query but rather a group of sql statements being sent to be executed dynamically and sequentially.  Your statements should run one after the other but it is hard to tell what is going on exactly because it appears we are just seeing a snippet.